# How can I prevent MathJax equations from overlapping with dropdown menus in Bootstrap 5.2?

Tags: html, navbar, bootstrap-5, mathjax

I'm building a website using Bootstrap 5.2 that includes MathJax equations and dropdown menus in the navbar. However, the MathJax equations are overlapping with the dropdown menus, making it difficult to use the menus. I've tried various CSS solutions but none have worked so far.

Here is my HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light p_code">
    <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="index.html">
        <img src=".png">TITLE</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
```

And so on (multiple links)... the links however are obscured by the MathJax equations:
[image]

What I've tried: I've attempted to use the z-index property, adjust the positioning of the MathJax elements, and modify the styles of the dropdown menus. However, none of these changes have resolved the issue.

I was expecting the dropdown menus to go over the top of the MathJax equations so that the menu was the priority, not the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
    /* MathJax Overlap */
.dropdown-menu {
  z-index: 1000; /* Set the z-index value of the dropdown menu */
}

.mjx-chtml {
  z-index: 999; /* Set the z-index value of MathJax elements */
}

.navbar {
  z-index: 9999;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  position: static;
  float: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Now the overlap is fixed once you know the correct classes, you can set their z-indexes appropriately.